# how to achieve the moving sparking effect with css and javascript as in css-tricks.com footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Here](http://css-tricks.com/gallery/think-less-do-more/) if you hover the  mouse on any of the links (i.e. 'The Bookshelf' link)in the footer, you get a tad sparking effect moving leftward.

I tried with firebug but could not make any clue as to how that is achieved.

Suppose I consider the always-showing white border (?) to be a single parent div, and the sparking divs to be individual ones inside that. Then when the mouse-hover takes place, jquery is supposed  to be used to apply background color or border for the child divs in left order . Even then the situation arises that those child divs make the height of the parent div  greater than the that of the children contrary to what is apparent in the url.

For the test scenario, I used a parent div  ( `class_1` ) and one child div ( `class_2` ) instead of many:
html:

```
<div class="class_1">
<div class="class_2"></div><!--end of class_2 -->

</div><!-- end of class class_1 -->
```

css:

```
.class_1{
height111:1px;

width:150px;
margin:0 auto;

border:2px solid red;


}
.class_2{

width:70px;
margin:0 auto;
border:1px solid green;


}
```

What should be the proper way?

Comment: the best person to answer the question would be Chris himself...I'm sure he'd be more than happy to show you...just go contact him at csstricks he monitors everything as far as I can tell

Comment: @MikeHometchko, let me try that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's completely CSS - no JS required. There's an empty `<span>` in each of the links with background transition attached.

Comment: i agree with @ahren its completely css. we dont need Js here. transition gives the sparkling effect.

Comment: @MikeHometchko, have posted the question in css-tricks.com here : http://css-tricks.com/forums/discussion/20007/how-to-achieve-the-moving-sparking-effect-with-css-and-javascript-as-in-css-tricks-com-footer#Item_1. If I get the solution from there before SO, I'll share that here.

Comment: @ahren, a bit more explanation please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/qYpck/

It's achieved using CSS only - a background gradient that is then transitioned on the hover of the parent `a` tag - the background-position is the property that gives it the illusion of *sparkles*.

```
<ul class="link-list">
  <li><a href="#">Link one<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link two<span></span></a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Link three<span></span></a></li>
</ul>
```

Take note of the empty `span`'s inside of the links.

This is the transition CSS that does the magic: (note you'll need to use browser prefixes for the `transition` property, like `-moz-` and `-o-` - they are present in the fiddle above but for readability and brevity I omitted them below)

```
.link-list a:hover>span, .link-list a:focus>span {
    background-position: -100% 0;
    transition: background 0.4s;
}
```

​The benefits of doing transitions with CSS are vast - it's things like:

- progressive enhancement (the *sparkle* effect isn't necessary to page function, so it's purely an aesthetic feature and won't slow down browsers that don't recognise it)
- CSS transitions are hardware accelerated, and generally smoother than JS animations
- removes strain on javascript engines

Read more: [Is there any advantage to using CSS animations over jQuery animations? (performance, or otherwise)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933659/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-css-animations-over-jquery-animations-performa)

To check which browsers will be supported with this technique, check caniuse.com

- http://caniuse.com/background-img-opts
- http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: cross-browser compatibility ?

Comment: Something like this shouldn't need to be cross-browser compatible. This isn't a necessary page function.

Comment: if you think the css rules in AR -MFS's answer to be necessary, please include them in your answer so that I can accept your answer.

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed - I have mentioned them in my answer. I included them in the JSFiddle demo, but tried to keep them out of my answer for clarity - but you're right, I should have mentioned browser prefixes. Amended.

Comment: @ahren +1 seems to be a complete answer to me `:)` nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
.link-list a:hover>span, .link-list a:focus>span {
    background-position:-100% 0;
    -webkit-transition:background 0.4s;
   -moz-transition:background 0.4s;
    -o-transition:background 0.4s;
    transition:background 0.4s
}
```

using CSS transition effect for background animation

Comment: why did u put my name in the answer?  not that I mind I just find it odd