# Add keyframes compatibility to Internet Explorer <=9

Tags: javascript, css, css-animations

How can I add keyframes compatibility to Internet Explorer 9 or less?

I'm thinking about some javascript code that reads the keyframes rules and convert them in javascript animations...

Is it possible?

Comment: no! instead use pure javascript/jquery

Comment: I'd like to add fallback for Internet Explorer and keep the advantages of CSS animations as default one..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933659/is-there-any-advantage-to-using-css-animations-over-jquery-animations-performa , is this helpful to you i dint go through this question but found relevant so posted here. take a look and let me know, apology for not being specific

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060223/using-css3-animations-in-ie9  now this is exactly what you want

Comment: yes the problem is not detect IE... is convert the CSS keyframes to javascript automatically.