# Image map not working with absolute positioned overlays

Tags: html, css, imagemap

I have a strcuture like: A container with an `image`, an `image map` and `overlays`. It should work like: ***While hovering over an `area`-element an overlay (at the very same position) should be shown.***

But I can't get it to work. It seems that the overlay is always blocking the `hover` of the areas.

What I've tried:

- `absolute` and `relative` positioning on the `image` and `map` and even the `areas`
- changing the order of elements in the DOM to img > overlay > map
- all variations of `z-indexes`

*How can I solve this problem?*

**Note**: I can't use `pointer-events: none` which would solve it, cause I need to support IE10.

Here's a simplified example:

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="//placehold.it/400" usemap="#map">
    <map name="map">
        <area shape="rect" coords="0, 0, 200, 200" href="">
    </map>
    <div class="overlay"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
}

map {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1000;
}

.overlay {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 500;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.overlay.active {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('areas').hover(
    function() {
        var e = $(this);
        $('.overlay').addClass('active');
        consoloe.log("enter");
      },
    function() {
        $('.overlay').removeClass('active');
        consoloe.log("enter");
    }
);
```

**jsFiddle**

[You can try it here.](https://jsfiddle.net/5rrbc8he/)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with CSS only without adding the active class with jQuery. [Here is the updated Fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/amitjsguy/5rrbc8he/2/)

I have targeted the hover on image as you have provided in your question. You can modify the class .container to your own class of area tag.

```
.image-className:hover .overlay {
    opacity: 1;
  }
```

If you want to achieve hover effect of same level element through CSS you can add a class to your map element and then add this css.

```
 .map-ClassName:hover + .overlay{
      opacity:1;     
}
```

Using CSS to achieve the overlay is much faster then doing it by js. [CSS vs Jquery Hover.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16675952/performance-pure-css-vs-jquery)

Comment: OP wants to `:hover` only the `area` not `container `

Comment: @dippas Yes but in the fiddle OP has provided with a image.

Comment: still there is an `area` (`map`)  that OP wants to hover on top of that image

Comment: As @dippas said, this doesn't solve the actual problem as the there will be multiple areas and multiple overlays. The example is simplified to demonstrate the problem itself.

Comment: @lampshade have you tested my answer?