# Jquery / CSS animation performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question around jquery creating css animations.

I just finished a jquery plugin that draws and animates dom elements with css. I am using jquery only to change and create css variables. I just tested my code on my phone and it seems to get very choppy. From what I have been reading CSS 3 animations are hardware accelerated while jquery are not.

So... are runtime css attributes created by jquery hardware accelerated?

For example, applying a css attribute to blades that use transition-duration 0.3s

```
$(blades).css({'width':'5px'}); to animate
```

See my code at http://andehlu.github.io/sensuJS/

Thank you.

Comment: Use translate3d(x, y, z) for better *accelerated* performances. Than, if triggered by jQuery or JS or `CSS3#animation` makes no difference, they'll translate beautifully.

Comment: Thanks Roko! Instead of width I'll use transform. Thank you.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I noticed the behaviour of transform:scaleX is different from jquerys width(). It scales the element plus everything inside it like background images. I was hoping only to increase the amount of width in pixels. is there a way to emulate width() with transform:scale?

Comment: Actually no problem Roko I found my mistake. I was starting with a 0 width ;)

Comment: possible duplicate of [what's faster? CSS3 transitions or jQuery animations?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984771/whats-faster-css3-transitions-or-jquery-animations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those types of transitions/animations which are not affecting DOM elements structure (eg. CSS trasnform's or opacity) are recommended to increase animation speed (instead of changing eg `width` or `top` what will affect other DOM elements) and yes CSS animations are faster than JS.

More information you can find [HERE](http://davidwalsh.name/css-js-animation) and

[HERE](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/look-and-feel/animations/animations-and-performance)