# Performance: CSS Transitions vs Javascript Effects

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

For the past 10 years I've been a fan of javascript transitions for all kinds of visual effects in the DOM.
A couple of years ago I experimented a little with CSS Transitions but the lack of support and the performance issues with the browsers back then made me rule them out as a solid alternative.

I am revisiting the topic now and have been looking for resources & tests which can show the difference between the 2 methods in terms of performance and support across devices and browsers.

**Question:** Can anyone suggest some good late 2012/2013 resources comparing the two approaches to simple animated effects?

**Mods:** I am aware that [similar questions exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999749/performance-of-css-transitions-vs-js-animation-packages), but with new browsers having become available, and improvements in implementations of the CSS `transition` spec I see this as a valid issue to re-raise since the last topics covering this were in 2010

Comment: Since you are **only** asking in terms of performance, **native** is always better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is: http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/

The conclusion is if you can use css for animation then you should :P

Comment: Note that [link-only answers are discouraged](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info), SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can try these resources:

1. http://www.css3maker.com/css3-transform.html
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform
3. http://tympanus.net/codrops/2011/10/24/creative-css3-animation-menus/
4. http://www.greywyvern.com/?post=337

and loads of more...

Comment: good start, especially from the support perspective but I was hoping to find some form of solid browser/device/performance/support tables. I'll get reading on your links :-)

Answer (score 1):

You have it here: [Why moving elements with translate() is better than pos:abs top/left](http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/)

Comment: nice, but this is only reflective of a couple of transition types and only showing chrome on mac (desktop/laptop device)