# How to measure the performance of CSS transitions and animations

Tags: html5-canvas, css-transitions, performance-testing, requestanimationframe, jsperf

I want to compare the performance of jQuery's animate function and pure CSS3 transitions. I've found out that there is a [requestAnimationFrame API](http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/Graphics/RequestAnimationFrame/Default.html) to measure the performance but it seems that it can only be used with the canvas element?

Is there a good way to test the performance of absolute positioning compared to CSS3 and canvas?

Is [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js) helpful and trustworthy? What are your experiences?

I built this [jsPerf test](http://jsperf.com/css3-translate-vs-jquery-animate). Unfortunately the jQuery.on method is not executed. :(

Comment: It would be helpful to know what you're trying to achieve with this; is it a simple CSS transition or are you developing a more complex animation that would need the canvas element?

Comment: I just want to use a simple transition. My goal is to just compare both technologies.

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that transitions/animation rules should be in the CSS as they are a presentational element, and JavaScript is meant for behaviour. For this reason I would stick with CSS transitions and leave JavaScript to do form validation/ajax/etc. But that doesn't mean that JavaScript is a wrong technology to use for animation, the very nature of the web being that you can use technologies in a variety of ways, because there is a lot of overlap between them.

I have a few links for you that I think you might find useful; [Paul Irish/Chris Coyier's discussion over translate](http://paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/), a video on [animations in CSS transitions vs Javascript](http://vimeo.com/22649023) and this [link showing the framerate comparison](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/blog/jquery-vs-css3-transitions/) between jQuery and CSS. **You can see in the third link that the CSS is definitely faster and smoother than the JavaScript**; I'm guessing because it is hardware accelerated.

Couple of stackoverflow questions that conclude similarly: [what's faster? CSS3 transitions or jQuery animations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10984771/whats-faster-css3-transitions-or-jquery-animations?lq=1) :: [Performance of CSS Transitions vs. JS animation packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999749/performance-of-css-transitions-vs-js-animation-packages)

---

You're right in that the `requestAnimationFrame` function is only available for the canvas element. I would recommend using that if you are planning to sync CSS transitions with canvas output, as that is what it is built for, rather than going with `setInterval`.

Comment: jQuery's animate is not the same thing as simply JavaScript in general. Other libraries like GSAP can be a lot faster than jQuery.