# Why does my smooth scroll not work properly?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I tried several different ways to scroll smoothly to the top.

I've used this code and some others, a specially for the `#top` attribute, but nothing seems to work.

Where did I go wrong?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Naamloos document</title>

<link href="basis.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="navigatie/menu.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script>$(document).ready(function(){
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click',function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var target = this.hash,
        $target = $(target);

        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            window.location.hash = target;
        });
    });
});</script>

</head><body>

<div id="header">
  <a href="#top"><img src="navigatie/bb.png" alt="" width="100" height="100" id="Image1"></a>
</div>

blabla content

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check console for errors.

Comment: Are we assuming that you've checked that the $("#top") element exists and is found by that query you have?

Also you're trying to trigger the scroll on both the html and the body separately? is there a reason for that duplication?  Any chance of a jsFiddle being posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with the other posts to add jQuery (your example didn't source it). Also, for smoother animations/transitions you may want to try using CSS transitions opposed to JS animations.

Here is a tutorial on CSS transitions to smooth scroll to the top using jQuery.

http://mitgux.com/smooth-scroll-to-top-using-css3-animations

Also, I personally am a huge fan of the jQuery transit library which uses jQuery to trigger all kinds of CSS transitions.

http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/

For more information on why CSS transitions are better than JS library animation effects [please see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999749/performance-of-css-transitions-vs-js-animation-packages).

Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

Include CDN version of [jQuery library](http://jquery.com/)

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

in your `<head>` section.

Or [Download jQuery library](http://jquery.com/download/) and use a local copy.

```
<script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
```

If you using local copy don't forget to put `jquery-1.10.2.min.js` in your root folder.

---

Also you can simplify your function

```
$(function() {
  $('#header a').click(function() {
    $('html, body').stop().animate({ scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top }, 900, 'swing'); 
  });
});
```

Comment: That'll help.  Also make sure some element with the ID `top` exists.